# HTTPS on non-default port results in Connection reset

Tags: java, iis-7, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a website setup in IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008R2 with two https bindings (using the same certificate), one on 443 and one on 8443. I can connect to both ports just fine using Chrome (Chrome mentions the protocol used is TLS 1.0).

I'm using Apache HTTPClient 4.2.6.

When connecting using Java 7 to any of the ports (using the following code) all is well

```
HttpUriRequest request = createRequest(inCtxt);

PoolingClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager);

HttpClient executingClient = isSupportCompressedResponse() ? new DecompressingHttpClient(
                client) : client;

HttpResponse response = executingClient.execute(request);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

return consume(entity);
```

Using Java 8 I get the following exception on port 8443, not on port 443

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:911)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:717)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:522)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:108)
```

Apparently, this may have something to do with the protocols, so I tried setting TLSv1 explicitly (as Java 8 adds [TLS1.2 as default](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_will_use_tls), I thought it might have something to do with that).

```
    SSLContext ctxt = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
    ctxt.init(new KeyManager[0],new TrustManager[]{new DefaultTrustManager()},new SecureRandom());
    SSLSocketFactory factory = new SSLSocketFactory(ctxt);
    Scheme https = new Scheme("https", 443, factory);
    f_connectionManager.getSchemeRegistry().register(https);
```

This seemed to work, so my original problem is solved, but I'm now really wondering why one port seems to support TLS1.2 when the other doesn't...

Comment: could you please share the imports